# Error when building: error[E0283]: type annotations needed in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting this error:

> error[E0283]: type annotations needed
> this method call resolves to `T`
> cannot infer type for type parameter `S` declared on the associated function `count`

There is a library that has this method:

```
pub fn count<'a, S: Display + Into<Cow<'a, str>>>(&self, name: S, val: i64, tags: Vec<String>)
```

And in the main code there is a call of this method:

```
self.metrics.count(teststring.into(), 1, vec![]);
```

How this issue can be resolved?

Comment: `teststring.into()` into what? The `name` parameter is generic and you don't specify any type hints, so the compiler can't read your mind and figure out which type to convert `teststring` into.

Comment: Basically, the signature of `count()` says "for `name` I'll accept any type `S` that can be converted into `Cow<str>`", and the call site says "for `name` I'll pass `teststring` converted into whatever type the function requires". So `teststring` must be converted into an unspecified type that can itself be converted into `Cow<str>`. Rust won't guess that type, even if there happened to be only one that matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue was pointed out in the comments. The compiler has no idea what you want to turn `testString` into (you may have encountered something similar when using `collect`).

To fix your issue (assuming `testString` has `impl`'s for both `Display` and `Into<Cow<str>>`) just pass in `testString`.

```
self.metrics.count( teststring, 1, vec![ ] );
```

If `testString` satisfies the generic constraints of the `count` method then you'll have no issues passing it in.

If, however, you really want to convert `testString` prior to passing it to `count` you can use the fully qualified syntax.

```
count( 
    Into::<Cow<str>>::into( testString ), 
    1, 
    vec![ ] 
);
```